# Release Client Certificates (X509Certificate2) from HttpWebRequest

Tags: httpwebrequest

I am creating an instance of X509Certificat2 from pfx file. The X509Certificate2 instance is attached to the HttpWebRequest.ClientCertificates.

After the request is made, I need to release the X509Certificates attached to the HttpWebRequet.

My code is as follows:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(pfxfilepath);
request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse;


X509CertificateCollection certCollection = request.ClientCertificates;
if ((certCollection != null) && (certCollection.Count > 0))
{
   foreach (X509Certificate2 certificate in certCollection)
   {
       // Free the certificate handle to the private key
       certificate.PrivateKey = null;

       // Release the rest of the certificate resources
       certificate.Reset();
   }
   request.ClientCertificates.Clear();
}
```

I wish to know whether this is the right approach to release the certificates attached to the Http Web request.